# Can the JVM call interrupt on a single threaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a single threaded program, which sometimes calls blocking methods (ie `process.waitFor`).

Can I be sure that the interrupted status of my thread is never set? Are there other conditions under which the JVM or the JRE standard library might decide to set the interrupt flag on my thread?

It seems true, but I couldn't find any mention about it in the Java docs.

Comment: There is no such thing as a single threaded Java program. Garbage collection, JIT compilation, signal dispatchers, etc. can all be run in separate threads from your main program.

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupted status"?

Comment: are you aware that Java specification allows thread to wake up from wait "without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup"? ([Object.wait(long)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) API docs, see also [JLS 17.8.1 Wait](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.8.1)). Per my understanding this won't set `interrupted` flag though

Comment: @gnat, yes, this is written in the Effective Java bible. However, as you mentioned, it does not throw the `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @mob, OK, I meant "Java program where I'm not creating any `Thread` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application does not create any "Java" (java.lang.Thread) threads then I believe you can safely assume that your main thread will never be interrupted, see this [dW article by Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).  Of course it is always possible that some library you're using could create threads and could potentially call interrupt() on your main thread, but it isn't likely.

In the end, I think you need to consider your requirements.  The main purpose of the interrupt support in threads is so that tasks (threads) can be cancelled and so that applications can shutdown cleanly, even if some threads are suspended in blocking calls.

Comment: I originally thought that a TERM signal would trigger the InterruptedException, but a little experimentation (java 1.6.0_26) shows that it does not. When a simple java process that is blocked in Process.waitFor() gets a TERM, it just exits. No further execution occurs.

Comment: @sceal, if a library that doesn't have your thread at hand, asks from the runtime all threads, pick yours, and interrupts it, well, you shouldn't use this library...

Comment: @sceal, the article you linked to tells what you can do with `InterruptedException`, but contains no information as of why can it be happened in your program (for example, `TERM` signal doesn't raise it, but maybe there's some other event?)

Comment: @Chi-Lan, There may be some other event that causes an InterruptedException, but if a TERM signal doesn't then I can't imagine what would reasonably cause it.
The article does address the typical cause of InterruptedException in the second section with the heading "Thread interruption".  It states: "If that thread is executing a low-level interruptible blocking method (when an another thread invokes interrupt() on a Thread) like Thread.sleep(), Thread.join(), or Object.wait(), it unblocks and throws InterruptedException."

Comment: ...continuing  Brian Goetz is usually pretty thorough, so I assume that if there were other causes of InterruptedException he would have addressed them.  A stretch I know, but until I see evidence to the contrary, I'm going to assume that there aren't any other mechanisms for causing InterruptedException.